# Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '.' after replacing ereg

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, preg-match

I had this original code:

```
/**
* IP address conversion: A.B.C.D -> log
*
* @param string $string IP Address: A.B.C.D
* @return long
* @access private
* @static
* @since 1.0
*/
private function convert2number($string)
{
    $pattern= "\"([0-9]+)\"";
    if (ereg($pattern, $string, $regs))
        return (int)$regs[1];
}

/**
* IP conversion
*
* @param string $address IP address in the A.B.C.D format
* @return long
* @access private
* @static
* @since 1.0
*/
private function IpAddress2IpNumber($address)
{
    $pattern = "([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+)";

    if (ereg($pattern, $address, $regs))
        return $number = $regs[1] * 256 * 256 * 256 + $regs[2] * 256 * 256 + $regs[3] * 256 + $regs[4];
    else
        return false;
}
```

Since PHP 5.3, `ereg` was Deprecated, I researched this, and I stumbled upon a suggestion to replace `ereg` with `preg_match`, I did so, and I got a new error:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '.' in geoip.php on line 222
```

Code:

```
/**
* IP conversion
*
* @param string $address IP address in the A.B.C.D format
* @return long
* @access private
* @static
* @since 1.0
*/
private function IpAddress2IpNumber($address)
{
    $pattern = "([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+)";

    if (preg_match($pattern, $address, $regs))
        return $number = $regs[1] * 256 * 256 * 256 + $regs[2] * 256 * 256 + $regs[3] * 256 + $regs[4];
    else
        return false;
}
```

How do I go about fixing this? Any recommendation? Thanks!

Comment: I removed the CakePHP tag, this has nothing to do with CakePHP.

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: You're recreating functionality that comes shipped with php http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. "." needs a "\" to avoid it be taken as any character.
2. the pattern needs delimiters for preg_match.

   ```
   $pattern = "|([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)|";
   ```

Comment: Don't just give away code. Explain why there is an issue and describe how to fix it. Like the man and his fishing rod

Comment: Thanks @zairwolf, What's the correct way? `$pattern = "/([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+)/"; ` OR  `$pattern = "|([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)|";`

Comment: A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.. Read this : http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to use delimiters with `preg_match`. See [the docs on this topic](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Comment: What do I need to edit? I'm new to PHP

Comment: Your regex has to be preceded and followed by a delimiter. Typical choices are `/`, `\``, and `~`.

Comment: @Sup3r Read the docs

Comment: @Sup3r Not sure what you mean. There are no `/`s in `\"([0-9]+)\"`.

Comment: Mind, where do I add it in my regex expression case?

Comment: Delimiters go at the very beginning and end of the expression.

Comment: Like I said, before and after. So, for example, `$pattern = "/([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+)/";`